# Firestore get() method code is executing at the very end of the function

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Below is my firestore code. you see the get method is executing at the very end of the function. Even though it is declared in the starting.

I am frustrating. if it is executing at the end then what is the use of this.

I don't know why firestore people are writing this type of codes. they don't have any answer to this in their website.

```
         function bookingsSubmit() { //This function saves the data of 
         //declaring database and all collections
         var db = firebase.firestore();
     const userColl = db.collection('users');
     const adminColl = db.collection('Admincrates');
     const bookingscoll = db.collection('bookings');
     const taskscoll = db.collection('tasks');

     //------Getting User Email
     var u = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
     var username;
     var lngth;
     var curList = [];
     //---------Getting Username
     userColl.doc(u).get().then((doc) =>{ //This is going into user collection for user's name
              //We got all the fields of user and going through all the fields
                 username = doc.data().name;
                 console.log(username);
                 lngth = doc.data().currencyList.length;
                 for(var l = 0; l<lngth;l++){curList.push(doc.data().currencyList[l])}
             });

     console.log(curList);
     //---------Getting the Booking Id and Incrementing the booking Id value
     taskscoll.doc('bookingId').update({ //Increment
         id: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
     });
     var bkngId;
     taskscoll.doc('bookingId').get().then((doc)=> { bkngId = doc.data().id}); //Getting Booking Id and saving                              into a variable 
 console.log(bkngId);

 //---------Getting Table values.
  var tbl_user = document.getElementById('booking_tbl'); //Reading the table of the user page middle 
  for(var i = 1; i < lngth; i++) {

  }

 var docData = {
     email: u,
     name: username,
     bookingId: bkngId,
     timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
     arrayExample: [5, true, "hello"],
     nullExample: null,
     objectExample: {
         a: 5,
         b: {
        nested: "foo"
         }
     }
 };
 console.log(docData);
 bookingscoll.add(docData).then(() => {
console.log("Document successfully written!");
});

 }
```

Comment: You may want to play around the async/await - for me it cleaned up my code drastically.

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` operations are ASYNCHRONOUS - your subsequent `.then()` waits for the `.get()` to finish - but that ALSO returns a promise, which your code DOES NOT WAIT FOR.

It will be VERY beneficial to understand the Javascript "event loop" in detail.  Foreground (i.e. synchronous) will take precedence UNLESS you at some point create an opportunity - i.e. some form of wait - for the "background" (event-driven) code to occur.  In your case, since you don't wait for the result of the `.get().then()` your code executes to the end of the function before the actual `.get()` event even occurs.

I suggest, if you have the choice, to use the `async/await` syntax, which often can help make this more obvious. Do not mix `async/await` with `.then()` - that will just lead to heartache (and difficult debug).